# How to save selected image from photo gallery to show any view controller in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uiimageview

I'm working on my app and i got stuck at one point.
There is one UIIMAGEVIEW  and one UPLOAD button.
So when user click UPLOAD button he get to photo gallery to select image after selecting image I'm showing that image on UIIMAGEVIEW.
So my question is:-
after showing image on UIIMAGEVIEW i want to save that image on app to show that same image on different View Controller.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can try this code snippet:

```
func saveImgToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileName = "image.png" // image name for identify particular image 
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("file saved")
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}


func loadImgFromDocumentDirectory(nameOfImage : String) -> UIImage {
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    if let dirPath = paths.first{
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(nameOfImage)
        let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        return image!
    }
    return UIImage.init(named: "default.png")!
}
```

Image name is a unique identifier for the image, while storing you are required to specify the image name "imageName", so it would be easy to fetch that particular image using the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image in a global variable. A global variable can be used through all the app. :

```
var imageSelected:UIImage? // Value will be nil if no image has been set

class ViewController1 {
    // Puts your image inside a global variable
    image = yourImage
}

class ViewController2 {
    // Uses the image that was defined inside the global variable
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIView!
    imageView.image = imageSelected
}
```